# Merge two triangules into one quad depending on shared vertices c#

Tags: c#

In a 2D context and supposing a mesh that does not have any holes.

How to form quads given vertices information from triangules - for example, taking the case of four triangles.

```
1       2       3
+-------+-------+
|\      |\      |
|  \    |  \    |
|    \  |    \  |
|      \|      \|
+-------+-------+
4       5       6
```

triangles are (assuming a clockwise winding order)

```
A=(1, 5, 4) B=(1, 2, 5) C=(2, 6, 5) D=(2, 3, 6)
```

The edges are

```
A=(1-5, 5-4, 4-1) B=(1-2, 2-5, 5-1) C=(2-6, 6-5, 5-2) D=(2-3, 3-6, 6-2)
```

triangles that share an edge are:

- A and B share exactly 1 edge 1-5 (because it is the same as 5-1)
- B and C share 2-5
- C and D share 2-6

Based on this information, it is possible to quad-ify as

- 2 quads `(1, 2, 5, 4)` and `(2, 3, 6, 5)`

However I do not know how to determine all quad-ifications and choose the one that left the least number of degenerate triangles.

I have all mesh triangles information (number of triangules, their vertices as show before)
Do you know any library or code snippet that I can start with?

Comment: Does the shape matter in any way or are (1, 2, 5, 4) and (1, 2, 6, 5) equally good quads on their own? And is the problem in 2D or can the mash be closed like a sphere? Can it have holes?

Comment: Shape does matter, well in case it can be well shaped quad like (1,2,5,4), The problem is in 2D. It does not have holes

Comment: What for do you want quads exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted an answer to a similar question here:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74807/convert-triangles-to-quads-of-a-mesh/74987#74987

You can probably brute force this without too much difficulty to get the perfect answer. In a real mesh, in most cases, you are actually going to have "patches" that can potentially be turned into quads, but you're not going to have an entire surface made up of a flat plane with a huge number of triangles, so I wouldn't personally spend a huge amount of time optimizing this. If you do have a flat plane made up entirely of triangles, I think your worst case is that you would have a triangle in between each quad. Since each quad is made up of two triangles, you're only look at a potential worst case of roughly 30%.

Since turning them into quads is a relatively fast process, I wouldn't spend a huge amount of time optimizing this, I would just create something that would bruce force every possible iteration, and pick the best one. You could terminate any particular check as soon as you were worse than your current best case. If you randomized your starting points, you wouldn't have to check everything.